# Finding halfway point along route using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst, midpoint

I'm looking for a way to find the midpoint of a route. Instead of the geometric midpoint, I want to use travel time. The ultimate goal here is to find the travel time midpoint for a series of addresses.

Is this possible with Network Analyst?

I've built a Closest Facilities analysis layer. I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.6.